# Why I have Error in organizer while distributing the application (xcode 10)

Tags: xcode, app-store, distribute

I'm trying to update an iOS app in App Store, with a new macbook, but I have error in organizer:

> **Resolver: Install error - org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore Exception's name: java.io.IOException, Exception's message: Error
>   accessing
>   file:/Users/User/.itmstransporter/obr/1.12.0/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore-4.4.10.jar**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I learned today that Apple was doing [Java apps](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/itc0d5b535bf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All I needed was it download and install **iTMSTransporter**, it available in this path: https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/apdA3ae5a8b0?sub=apdA687d545d

Comment: Oh great Gods of Google and Stackoverflow!
You mighty keeper of knowledge
Master of the Internet.

THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU